# Adjoint representation is Lie algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $T_g:=L_g R_{g^{-1}}: G \rightarrow G$ be the standard automorphism of a Lie algebra, then $Ad_g:=DT_g(e): \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g} $is called the adjoint representation. Now, I want to show that $[Ad_g \xi, Ad_g  \eta] = Ad_g [\xi,\eta].$ Here, $\xi,\eta \in \mathfrak{g}.$

So the goal is to see that $Ad$ respects also the Lie-Bracket. Unfortunately, I don't see how this can be shown.  (and I cannot use more properties here, as I only have this basic definitions available).

Comment: Is your first upper-case $G$ actually meant to be the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$? And, usually upper-case Ad is $Ad(g):\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak g$ with $g$ in the Lie _group_. Then the derivative of Ad is lower-case ad, which seems to be what your question is about. Clarify? (At some level, the Jacobi identity is exactly the assertion that lowercase-ad is a Lie algebra hom, without reference to a Lie group.)

Answer (score 1):

By definition $Ad_g=(T_g)_\ast$ and $T_g$ is a diffeomorphism.

Given a diffeomorphism $f$ it's true that $f_\ast[X,Y]=[f_\ast X,f_\ast Y]$ as this answer shows: [Pushforward of Lie Bracket](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365535/pushforward-of-lie-bracket)