# The image of a vector field under the differential of a diffeomorphism is a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

I'm learning about vector fields on manifolds, and I'm slightly confused about the following result.

> Let $M$ and $N$ be differentiable manifolds, $\varphi:M\to N$ a diffeomorphism, and $\mathrm d\varphi: TM \to TN$ its differential. 
>   If $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then $\mathrm d\varphi(X) \in \mathfrak{X}(N)$.

Here $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ denotes the space of differentiable vector fields $X:M\to TM$.
Of course, $\mathrm d\varphi(X)$ is a slight abuse of notation, and should be understood as the map
$$ \mathrm d\varphi(X) : \varphi(p) \mapsto (\varphi(p), \mathrm d\varphi_p(X_p)). $$

Now my problem is that I don't see why we must require $\varphi$ to be a diffeomorphism. I can see that we need $\varphi$ to be bijective in order for the map above to even be well-defined on the whole $N$, and of course $\varphi$ must be differentiable to be able to perform the differentiation,
but what is the point of the inverse being differentiable (or even continuous for that matter)?

Comment: I agree, there's no need for $\phi$ to be a diffeomorphism to define $d\phi$.  Are you sure you have the context correct?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for your response. This result is a part of a theorem which states that the differential $\mathrm d\varphi$ is in that case a Lie algebra homomorphism, but I was almost certain that the homomorphy here has nothing to do with the fact that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, so I assumed that it has to do something with the result in my post. See Proposition 4.28. on page 49 in [Riemannian geometry](http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Riemann.pdf).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365535/pushforward-of-lie-bracket for more information.  Maybe $\varphi$ needs to be a diffeomorphism to extends from points to vector fields.  Not seeing it at the moment, but the top-voted answer mentions it too.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I see it now.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)  I'll go ahead and write an answer.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Looking forward to your answer. Wiki says "In some situations, given a X vector field on M, there is a **unique** vector field Y [...]", and I agree that for uniqueness we need a diffeomorphism. However doesn't the result in my post still hold (possibly without uniqueness) even if $\varphi$ is not a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as $\varphi \colon M \to N$ is differentiable, the map $d\varphi_p$ is a vector space homomorphism from $T_pM$ to $T_{\varphi(p)}N$ for any $p \in M$.  So $\phi$ pushes tangent vectors forward without needing invertibility.

But if a vector field $X$ on $M$ is to push forward to a vector field $\varphi_* X$ on $N$, we need a vector $(\varphi_* X)_q$ in every $T_qN$.  There's no way to do this unless $q$ is in the image of $\varphi$.  So we require $\varphi$ to be surjective.  Then if $\phi(q) = q$, we can define $(\varphi_* X)_q = d\varphi(X)_p$  In order for this to be well-defined, we need for $\varphi$ to be one-to-one.  So we can say
$$
    (\varphi_* X)_q = d\varphi(X)_{\varphi^{-1}(q)}
$$
I assume you need $\varphi^{-1}$ to be differentiable in order for $\varphi_*X$ to be smooth.

As examples, consider $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$, $N = \mathbb{R}$ with coordinate $y$, and $\varphi(x_1,x_2) = x_1$.  Then clearly $d\varphi$ takes $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$ to $0$.  What should $\varphi_*\left(x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)$ be though?  You'd have to choose a lifting $\psi\colon N \to M$ (in other words, a function $x_2(y)$), which seems problematic from a naturality standpoint.

Or $M = N = \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi(x) = x^3$.  Let $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. 
 Then $d\varphi(x,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) = (x^3,3x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$  To define $\varphi_*x X$ at a point $y \in N$, you'd need to take $d\varphi(y^{1/3},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) = (y,3y^{2/3}\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$.  This isn't going to be smooth at $y=0$.

You can read more about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)).

Comment: Ah! Now I see it. Thank you for such a detailed answer!

Comment: Thanks for giving me the chance to work it out.  In the 20 years since I've been a grad student, the best advice I can give now that I wish I'd heeded then is: work out small examples!