# Confusion about definitions in differential geometry / Pushforward of Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, lie-derivative, pushforward

I am confused with the definition and notation in differential geometry.
Take the solution to the problem reply [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365535/pushforward-of-lie-bracket) for example.

X,Y are Vectorfields on M and $\psi: M \rightarrow N$, $g\in C^{\infty}(N)$
Can someone explain to me why:
$$ \psi_*[X,Y](g) = [X,Y](g\circ \psi) $$
Our definition in class was the following:
$$ \psi_*X = T\psi \circ X \circ \psi^{-1} $$
Shouldn't the same thing happen here:
$[X,Y]$ is also a vector field on M. Thus $\psi_*[X,Y]$
should be a vector field on N. Hence, I would think that:
$$ \psi_*[X,Y] = T\psi \circ [X,Y] \circ \psi^{-1} $$
How do these definitions reconcile?

Also am I correct that $X(f) = Tf(X)$ where Tf is the tangent map?

I would very much appreciate every help!

Thanks in advance!

Max

$\phantom{4}$

$\phantom{4}$

EDIT:
Is that correct?
We have in general:
$$ \psi_*X(f) = Tf(\psi_*X) = Tf(T\psi \circ X \circ \psi^{-1}) = Tf \circ T\psi \circ X \circ \psi^{-1} = T(f\circ \psi)(X) \circ \psi^{-1} = X(f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} \quad (*)$$
We can thus write:
$$ \psi_*[X,Y](f) \stackrel{*}{=} [X,Y](f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} = XY(f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} - YX(f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}  $$
$$ = X(Y(f\circ \psi)) \circ \psi^{-1}-Y(X(f\circ \psi)) \circ \psi^{-1}  $$
$$ = X(Y(f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} \circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}-Y(X(f\circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} \circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1} $$
$$ \stackrel{*}{=} X(\psi_*Y(f) \circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}-Y(\psi_*X(f)  \circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}   $$
$$ \stackrel{*}{=} \psi_*X(\psi_*Y(f)) - \psi_*Y(\psi_*X(f) )   $$
$$ = [\psi_*X,\psi_*Y](f) $$

For that I assumed, that:
$$ X(f) = Tf(X) $$
Is that correct?

Comment: Do you know where $g\circ \psi$ is living?

Comment: Note that your second expression assume $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism. That said, both statments are true. One can view a vector field on $M$ as a smooth section $M\to TM$, or as a derivation $C^\infty M\to C^\infty M$. The two expressions for the pushforward correspond to these two ways of viewing vector fields.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The second definition takes a point on N and gives us a Tangentvector in TN. But the first takes a point in M? I thought the pushforward of the Vectorfield should make it take points on N. What am I misunderstanding?