# Why is $X_p(Y(g\circ f))-Y_p(X(g\circ f)) = X_p(f_*(Y)(g)\circ f) - Y_p(f_*(X)(g)\circ f)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365535/pushforward-of-lie-bracket/) there is a question in  comment at the bottom of the most voted up question. It asks:

If $f:M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism (and $f_*$ the pushforward) between manifolds and $X, Y$ two smooth vector fields on $M$ then why is this true?

$$X_p(Y(g\circ f))-Y_p(X(g\circ f)) = X_p(f_*(Y)(g)\circ f) - Y_p(f_*(X)(g)\circ f)$$

For me, I'm confused because my understanding is that $Y(g \circ f) = f_*(Y)(g)$ but this seems to indicate that, instead, $Y(g \circ f) = f_*(Y)(g) \circ f$. I realize I can't be correct since $f_*(Y)(g) \in C^{\infty}(N)$ and so $X_p$ could not act on it, but I'm still not sure why this equality is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism between two manifolds, let $X$ be a vector field on $M$ and $g:N\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth functions. Then for every $p\in M$ we have $$X_p(g\circ f)=(f_*X)_{f(p)}(g)=\Big((f_*X)(g)\Big)(f(p)).$$
As you said in the question, this is the only identity that *can* make sense. To prove it, notice that $X_p(g\circ f)$ can be rewritten as $\mathrm{d}(g\circ f)_p(X)$. The naturality of pullbacks gives you $$\mathrm{d}(g\circ f)_p(X)=\mathrm{d}(f^*g)_p(X)=\big(f^*\mathrm{d}g\big)_p(X)=(\mathrm{d}g)_{f(p)}(f_*X)$$
which is just what we wanted to show.